# Tsql union of sub queries that each require an ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I apologize if the answer for this is somewhere else. I looked around and I could not see a simple solution. I have a query that I would like to run. I don't care about the order of the union set, only that the inner queries return the correct data which is the "Largest Areas".

```
(SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [geo].[Areas] WHERE CountryID = @CountryID AND (TypeID = 'City')
ORDER BY [ShapeArea] DESC) as BiggestCities
    UNION ALL
(SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [geo].[Areas] WHERE CountryID =  @CountryID AND (TypeID = 'National park')
ORDER BY [ShapeArea] DESC) as BiggestParks
```

But T-sql won't let me have ORDER BY on the sub-queries, only on the whole Union... Help appreciated! I would really prefer not to have to create temporary tables or anything like that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * 
          FROM [geo].[Areas] 
         WHERE CountryID = @CountryID 
           AND (TypeID = 'City')
      ORDER BY [ShapeArea] DESC) as BiggestCities
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 5 * 
          FROM [geo].[Areas] 
         WHERE CountryID =  @CountryID 
           AND (TypeID = 'National park')
      ORDER BY [ShapeArea] DESC) as BiggestParks
```

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I needed. Muchas Gracias :)

Comment: de nada, It's a quick and dirty, I thought someone else would have something more elegant, haven't had time to try out @Joe Stefanelli's

Comment: @PaulMcCowat can you tell me how can I build this query with SQLiteQueryBuilder's buildUnionSubQuery method and buildUnionQuery Method and content providers ?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.* /* Excluding RowNum */
  FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TypeID ORDER BY [ShapeArea] DESC) as RowNum
          FROM [geo].[Areas]
          WHERE CountryID = @CountryID 
            AND TypeID IN ('City', 'National park')
       ) t
  WHERE t.RowNum <= 5
```

Comment: Just what I was going to post--though since that SELECT * will return "new" column RowNum, I was putting in the old "avoid SELECT * advice.

Comment: @Phillip: Absolutely agree on avoiding the `SELECT *`, but it's the best I can do here without knowing the column names. Also note that I included a comment indicating the outer `SELECT` should exclude the `RowNum` column.

Comment: This is slower. I knew already, but I tested anyway - both this and Paul's answer - and confirm the general plan will be slower.